# MEAN stack how to compare input password with hash and salt string saved in database

Tags: node.js, jwt, mean-stack, passport-local

I have password as my user authentication middleware, and I also implement jwt, so I would like to compare if the post password is the same as the one in database(saved as hash and salt).
But this

```
console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.hash));
```

alway return me false.

How should I modify it in order to correct this problem? Is there a way to modify the code without using bcrypt?

Thanks a lot.

For user register and login:

```
 router.route('/register')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('register', { });
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
      if (err) {
        return res.render('register', {info: 'Sorry. That username already exists. Try again.'});
      }
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  });

router.route('/login')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user: req.user });
  })
  .post(passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

For jwt authentication I have:

```
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
    var collection = db.get('accounts');

    // find the user
    collection.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        } else if (user) {


            // check if password matches
            console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.hash));

            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.hash)) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
            } else {

                // if user is found and password is right
                // create a token
                var payload = {
                    admin: user.admin   
                }
                var token = jwt.sign(payload, app.get('superSecret'), {
                    expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
                });

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                });
            }       

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like while storing the passport in your regsiter api, you are not using bcrypt to encrypt it. You are directly storing the password which is coming in request body

Comment: Yeah, but I used passport middleware, so inside database there are only hash and salt.

Comment: If you have salt. Then you you should hash the login password using same salt then compare it

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, actually to recall passport, I need to call passport.authenticate:

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res,next) {

    passport.authenticate('local', {
            session: false
        }, function(err, user, info) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                if (!user) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    //But here how do I know username invalid or password invalid?????
                }
                console.log("Success");

            })(req, res, next);
    });

});
```

Another question is inside if(!user) how do I know is username invalid or password invalid??????
If anyone knows the answer welcome to post, thanks.